# FormBuilderDropdown broke inside futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I put the FormBuilderDropdown inside FutureBuilder so when I press on it will rebuild infinitely and will not enter the FormBuilderDropdown if anyone can give me a proper solution

and this is my code

```
FutureBuilder(
                         future: widget.fetchBrands(yearValue),
                          builder:
                              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                            var snap = snapshot.data;
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.waiting) {
                              return Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              );
                            }
                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              if (yearValue == null) {
                                return Container(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Select the manufacture year to Select Brand",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.red[800],
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                    ),
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                              return Center(
                                child: new Text('Error'),
                              );
                            }
                            snap.forEach((key, brand) {
                              brands.add(brand['make']);
                            });

                            brands = brands.toSet().toList();
                            brands.sort();
                            return
                
                                FormBuilderDropdown(
                              key: ValueKey("Brands"),
                              name: "Brands",
                              items: brands
                                  .map(
                                    (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                      child: Text(e),
                                      value: e,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                  .toList(),
                              validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose(
                                [
                                  FormBuilderValidators.required(
                                    context,
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Brands',
                                labelStyle:
                                    Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,

                                
                              ),
                             
                              hint: Text('Select Brand'),
                              allowClear: true,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  brandValue = value;
                                  carValue = null;
                                  carsName.clear();
                                 
                                });
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
```

before the new version of FormBuilder, this works well

I do temp solution that after I get the data I remove the future and build a new one without future but this solution not good enough because it takes two tap to open the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
future: widget.fetchBrands(yearValue),
```

This means, every time `build` is called, you will start over and fetch the brands. You only want to fetch them *once*, yo you should only call the method once.

You want this line in `initState` where it runs only once:

```
brandsFuture = widget.fetchBrands(yearValue);
```

and then use that one future in your build method:

```
future: brandsFuture,
```

obviously you need to declare `brandsFuture` as a field in your state class.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the problem with this is the value of ```yearValue``` get it from another dropdown so I cant put the function ```widget.fetchBrands(yearValue);``` in inistate

anyway thanks for your answer sir

Comment: Well, you need to put it somewhere that is **not** the `build` function.